# Configuring Hangfire in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I need to configure the hangfire inside .NET Core 2.1 project based on database connectionstring selected by user.

**What I have tried :-**

I have added required NuGet packages(Owin and Hangfire) and configure the hangfire inside *Configure* method of *Startup*(Startup.cs) class as follows

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    //Other required code goes here

var storage1 = new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseConnectionString"]);
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/Dashboard", new DashboardOptions(), storage1);
}
```

It is working fine. but the problem is *I want to configure the hangfire based on the databaseconnectionstring selected by user using UI*(User will select databaseconnectionstring from dropdown).

**Question(s) :-**

- Is it possible to configure the hangfire inside controller? How?
- Can we pass *IApplicationBuilder* inside controller?(To configure the hangfire as did in Startup.cs)
- Using middleware can I do this? How?
- Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with IoC by setting `JobStorage` to your custom implementation

```
services.AddScoped<JobStorage>(x =>
{
    // resolve your storage, from IHttpContextAccessor or some other way
    return new SqlServerStorage(...);
});

services.AddScoped<IBackgroundJobClient>(x => new BackgroundJobClient(
    x.GetRequiredService<JobStorage>(),
    x.GetRequiredService<IBackgroundJobFactory>(),
    x.GetRequiredService<IBackgroundJobStateChanger>()));
```

This would mean that `JobStorage` and `IBackgroundJobClient` are now Scoped and resolved on each request. This is just an idea, you'll probably need to do some more configuration that's required for your case to work.

Comment: Thanks for answer. If you give small working example it will be really helpful.